# include javax.print apis on android

Tags: android, printing

I am currently working on custom android printing service for IPP printers. javax.print apis along with jipsi.jar works perfectly fine on java. Is there a way to import javax.print apis on android.

Comment: AFAIK, no. Certainly they are not part of the Android SDK.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In my custom print service, I have written logic to search for printers on the network. The print job is also getting queued. But it is not reaching the printer. Will the OS take care of delivering it to the printer, or should we explicitly write logic to send requests to printer?.

Comment: If you are writing the print service, my understanding is that you need to get the print jobs to the printer. IOW, that is the point behind writing a print service.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, your info has been helpful. I have tried CUPS with android, but it needs a ipp printers shared over server. Is there any approach that you can suggest me. Can we use PCL to communicate with ipps printers?

Comment: Talk to the printer manufacturer. Bear in mind that what your `PrintService` gets is a PDF file. Your printer manufacturer can tell you how best to deliver a PDF to the printer for printing.

Comment: Thanks, will try and do that.